# Send email using Office 365 with SharePoint file as attachment

Tags: email, powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have code that works to send mail via Office 365 by utilizing the `System.Net.Mail.Message` class.  A new requirement is that my users want to be able to have a document/file contained in a SharePoint Online document library attached to the email.  To me I have two options:

- Download the file first, and then attach it to my mail message
- Figure out a way to attach the file straight from SharePoint so I don't have the download the file first.

Has anyone done the second option?  I'm at a loss as to how I would even begin to do that outside of something like streaming the contents of the file and building the attachment on the fly.  I'd prefer to not have to download the file locally first.  I see a variety of options when downloading a document from a document library, so I'm not concerned with writing that code or reusing something someone else has put together (and shared graciously I might add).

Things I've already looked at:

- SharePoint Online Management Shell PowerPhell Module (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588)
- Using the URL as the attachment (didn't think that would work, but hey, gotta try.  I even got SharePoint Online Authentication working, but no dice on linking direct to the URL)
- SharePointPNP Module (https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell)

Anybody out there had to do this and had any success?

Comment: Hi, this is a weird request since the point of having a SharePoint is to avoid multiplying files (e.g. when sending them around as attachments). Why not send a link to the file?

Comment: Hey - thanks for the reply.  I agree with you on the entire approach of sharepoint.  However, we're sending this outside of our organization and that would require the recipient user (in our case due to security) to register an account for access.

Comment: Maybe `[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail()` accepts different types of attachments (I haven't read the doc _yet_)? Nevermind: _SPUtility.SendEmail doesn't support sending attachments_ sigh. I'd go for the _download/attach/email_ approach.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm working on the download script now.

Comment: Hey! Just an idea. You could use OneDrive to sync the sharepoint site/folder so you have the file updated locally, and then just use Powershell's `send-MailMessage` to send the file as an attachment.

Edit: Reading your info more carefully, this might not be what you want since you have to "download" the file.

Comment: There is no way to add a file as an attachment in a mail without downloading it. Instead of downloading a file to disk you can download it to memory (actually, if you use the Sharepoint REST API you get a byte array of the file as a result so inserting this into the mail is easy - the file doesn't have to be downloaded to disk since you can put this in a memorystream which can be used as attachment)

Comment: Thanks @David.  I had this thought too, just trying to handle it all in code as opposed to relying on that external service.  Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: @bluuf Thanks for this.  This is the route I was heading down yesterday - I appreciate you outlining the overall flow for it.